# Being Descriptive

Tags: problem-gm, narration

I realise the title is somewhat ironic.

I have started playing a new game, it is exciting, well-paced, suspenseful; everything an rpg-er like me could ask for.

The issue is the description of, well, everything, is lacking. The GM is feeling a bit inferior in that respect. Some examples might be:

- *You are in the town square, with a large group of people in it, not too packed, but movement will be somewhat restricted*
- *A short, gruff man answers the door. He only stands about waist-height and appears to be drunk.*
- *You enter the clearing, The forest surrounds on all sides, save a gap in the trees opposite you. A web covers the ground with a hole in the middle that looks like a tunnel entrance*

It's not that he's withholding information, he just doesn't have anything else to say.

He approached me about it, saying he wanted to improve on his story telling, and I gave him some advice, but I don't really have much experience in that area myself. What practices can he implement to try and boost him along to improving?

Answer (score 2):

Not to experienced with this myself, but what I try to do is close my eyes, picture the environment, and then describe it in under a minute. This should be enough to give a good setting for the PCs, I usually relegate 10-15 seconds for an npc and 45 for an npc of importance.